# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react-redux When Delete Item reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an error after clicking the delete button saying:Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.I'm new in React Redux JS.
Please see my code below of my component reducers and actions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1fgV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLhuC.png)

Comment: state.tenants.tenants vs state.tenants ?

Comment: I don't see `map` in the delete function, or the delete action of the reducer. Are you possibly mapping somewhere else, like inside your component's render?

Comment: Can you please post your code as text? It's really hard to check in this way. Thanks!

Comment: Would suggest sharing the relevant code block so that it will be easier to identify the real issue.